# How should I modify the response which is returned to me by AWS DynamoDB Query through AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I have built a Query API for AWS DynamoDB through the AWS API Gateway. Here's a sample response I get after a successful query :

```
{
   "Count":2,
   "Items":[
      {
         "StoreID":{
            "S":"STR100"
         },
         "OrderID":{
            "S":"1019"
         },
         "Date":{
            "S":"22nd May"
         }
      },
      {
         "StoreID":{
            "S":"STR100"
         },
         "OrderID":{
            "S":"1020"
         },
         "Date":{
            "S":"22nd May"
         }
      }
   ],
   "ScannedCount":2
}
```

---

What I want to do is, when the response reaches the API Gateway (before it reaches the user) I want to modify it. I would like to do the following changes to the coming response -

- Firstly, remove the `ScannedCount` value. (keep the `Count` one)
- Then remove all the `"S": "<value>"` : value should appear directly, like `"StoreID": "STR100"`

So, the modified response should look like :

```
{
   "Count":2,
   "Items":[
      {
         "StoreID":"STR100",
         "OrderID":"1019",
         "Date":"22nd May"
      },
      {
         "StoreID":"STR100",
         "OrderID":"1020",
         "Date":"22nd May"
      }
   ]
}
```

I hope you understand my problem - Any help is appreciated!
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the blog article [Using Amazon API Gateway as a proxy for DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/)

> Navigate to Integration Response and expand the 200 response code by choosing the arrow on the left. In the 200 response, expand the Mapping Templates section. In Content-Type choose application/json then choose the pencil icon next to Output Passthrough.

And for your example the template should look like this:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "Count": "$inputRoot.Count",
    "Items": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
            "StoreID": "$elem.StoreID.S",
            "OrderID": "$elem.OrderID.S",
            "Date": "$elem.Date.S"
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the blog link! You have solved my problem :)